# Has-one relation is not working (GORM) as expected with documentation

Tags: go, grails-orm, go-gorm

I have the following structures

```golang
type User struct {
   gorm.Model
   FirstName                 string
   LastName                  string 
   Contact                   Contact 
}

type Contact struct {
   gorm.Model
   Email                      string
}
```

Whenever I try to start my project (which AutoMigrate) tables it says

`invalid field found for struct User's field Contact: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface`

But that's how is implemented on the documentation... weird.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

After that I tried with belongs to but different

```golang
type User struct {
    UserID                    int64
    FirstName                 string
    LastName                  string
    ContactID                 int64
    Contact                   Contact
}

type Contact struct {
    ContactID                  int64
    Email                      string
}
```

This compiles but when trying to Update the contact it behaves weird.
If I try to update the following JSON

`{"first_name": "John", "last_name": "Doe", "contact": {"phone": "555-555", "cellphone":"555-551"}}`

To the expected JSON:

`{"first_name": "John", "last_name": "Doe", "contact": {"phone": "555-553", "cellphone":"555-551"}}`

With `r.db.GetDB().Preload("Contact").Updates(&User)` and `r.db.GetDB().Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).Updates(&User)` the result was:
`{"first_name": "John", "last_name": "Doe", "contact": {"phone": "555-553", "cellphone":null}}`

The query was somewhat weird:
`UPDATE "users" SET "first_name"='Johnn',"contact_id"=1,"updated_at"=1669409959318 WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "user_id" = 1`

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `UserID` field in `Contract` table. Without this reference can't be possible that means foreign key can't be created.

```
type User struct {
   gorm.Model
   FirstName                 string
   LastName                  string 
   Contact                   Contact 
}

type Contact struct {
   gorm.Model
   Email                      string
   UserID                     uint
}
```

Comment: Wait, why? I mean, a User has a Contact... that doesn't make sense from a database design POV. Is this a Gorm thing?

Comment: Yes. This is [gorm default](https://gorm.io/docs/has_one.html) and it's wise to do like this in real life. That means association key shouldn't be on the owner side. Because in future user may have multiple contract.